# Measure compute shader execution time in Vulkan

Tags: android, gpu, opencl, vulkan, compute-shader

I'm investigating Vulkan and for the time being I'm interested at performance in particular.

I have written a computing shader and now I want to measure it's performance. I have found a few useful articles about time queries and use them in such a way:

Create Query Pool:

```
    VkQueryPoolCreateInfo queryPoolCreateInfo = {
            .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_QUERY_POOL_CREATE_INFO,
            .pNext = NULL,
            .queryType = VK_QUERY_TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
            .queryCount = 2
    };
    
    CALL_VK(vkCreateQueryPool(info.device, &queryPoolCreateInfo, nullptr, &queryPool));
```

Write TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT right after CommandBuffer begin:

```
VkCommandBufferBeginInfo cmd_buf_info = {};
cmd_buf_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
cmd_buf_info.pNext = NULL;
cmd_buf_info.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;
cmd_buf_info.pInheritanceInfo = NULL;

CALL_VK(vkBeginCommandBuffer(cmdBuffer, &cmd_buf_info));

vkCmdResetQueryPool(cmdBuffer, queryPool, 0, 1);
vkCmdWriteTimestamp(cmdBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT, queryPool, 0);
```

Write BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT right after buffer dispatch and before it's ending:

```
    vkCmdDispatch(cmdBuffer, workgroup_x, workgroup_y, workgroup_z);

#ifdef __VK_DEBUG_WARP_AFFINE
    vkCmdWriteTimestamp(cmdBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT, queryPool, 1);
#endif

    CALL_VK(vkEndCommandBuffer(cmdBuffer));
```

And reading timestamps:

```
uint64_t ts[2];
CALL_VK(vkGetQueryPoolResults(info.device, queryPool, 0, 2, sizeof(uint64_t) * 2, ts, sizeof(uint64_t), VK_QUERY_RESULT_64_BIT));

double msTime = (ts[1] - ts[0]); // / 1e+6f;
LOG_W2(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Vulkan execution time = %.2f nanoseconds, %.2f ms", msTime, msTime / 1000000);
```

Now, I see that performance figures are somewhat relevant, and the value varies in `8000-12000` nanoseconds range. But the problem is - exactly the same compute shader in `OpenCL` runs roughly in `0.4-1.0` MILLISECONDS!! I mean the difference is just unbelievable also considering the fact that I'm using float buffers in `Vulkan` and char buffers in `OpenCL` (`Vulkan` doesn't support 8bit storage on my Android phone).

This performance difference is hardly to be valid, so my question is - did I do something wrong measuring pipeline performance time? Please advise!

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**

How I measure performance in OpenCL

Create queue with debugging enabled:

```
cl_command_queue_properties p = 0;
  if (profilingEnabled) {
    p |= CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE;
  }

  cl_command_queue q = clCreateCommandQueue(m_main->getContext(), m_main->getDevice(), p, err);
```

Execute kernel with event to fixate execution time:

```
cl_event profile_event;
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(
        commandQueue,
        kernel1,
        2,
        NULL,
        affine_work_size,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL,
        &profile_event
);
```

And then fetch time measures:

```
clWaitForEvents(1, &profile_event);

cl_ulong queued;
clGetEventProfilingInfo(profile_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_QUEUED, sizeof(cl_ulong), &queued,
                        NULL);

cl_ulong submit;
clGetEventProfilingInfo(profile_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_SUBMIT, sizeof(cl_ulong), &submit,
                        NULL);

cl_ulong start;
clGetEventProfilingInfo(profile_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START, sizeof(cl_ulong), &start,
                        NULL);
cl_ulong completed;
clGetEventProfilingInfo(profile_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END, sizeof(cl_ulong),
                        &completed, NULL);

size_t executionTime = completed - start;
size_t setupTime1 = submit - queued;
size_t setupTime2 = start - submit;
size_t totalTime = completed - queued;

LOG_W2(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "%s execution time = %.2fms", kernel_name.c_str(),
       (completed - start) / 1000000.f);
overallWorkTime += executionTime;

LOG_W2(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "%s queued_submit time = %.2fms", kernel_name.c_str(),
       (submit - queued) / 1000000.f);
overallSetupTime += setupTime1;

LOG_W2(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "%s submit_start time = %.2fms", kernel_name.c_str(),
       (start - submit) / 1000000.f);
overallSetupTime += setupTime2;

LOG_W2(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "%s total time = %.2fms", kernel_name.c_str(),
       (completed - queued) / 1000000.f);
overallTotalWorkTime += totalTime;
```

Comment: 8000 nanosections is 8 *micro* seconds, which is much shorter than 0.4 *milli* seconds. Also, how are you querying the time in OpenCL?

Comment: Hello Nicol! Thank you for your attention to my post. I have provided the logic how I query the time. Could you please elaborate what info should I provide as well?

Comment: You provided the logic for querying time in *Vulkan*. I asked about OpenCL.

Comment: Hello @NicolBolas! I have provided an OpenCL logic. Sorry for misunderstanding you the first time